# Razor onchange not recognizing @variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, onchange

```
 @{
            foreach (CaseCount cc in @Model.CaseCounts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@cc.Country</td>
                    <td>@string.Format("{0:n0}", cc.RegisteredCases)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Reports", new SelectList(@Model.ReportList, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "window.location.href='Reports/RenderReport/' + this.value + '/' + @cc.Country;" })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
```

@cc.Country is not recognized. The action in controller is not triggered :(

If I remove @cc.Country or simply put it hard-coded, it works

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting the @cc.Country in as text inside quotes. Try this:

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("Reports", new SelectList(@Model.ReportList, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "window.location.href='Reports/RenderReport/' + this.value + '/'" + cc.Country + ";" })</td>
```

Comment: This helped, except that the final correct line is: <td>@Html.DropDownList("Reports", new SelectList(@Model.ReportList, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "window.location.href='Reports/RenderReport/' + this.value + '/" + @cc.Country + "';" })</td>